# Content of a UITableViewCell does not want to fit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have made a little sample project that reproduces my error:

[TableViewBug.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtko4tmy8ftyrqa/TableViewBug.zip?dl=0)

What happens is that this code, when run under iOS 7.1, produces a `UITableView` with cells, whose content will not stay at the margins, where it should be according to the constraints, and where it even says it is, according to it's frame. Meaning, when I log `cell.contentView.frame` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, it says it is at x:0 y:0, but when I look at the UI, most of the views have been compressed, and the last one is even too large and has been clipped, because of the longer label.

[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ym0scfqo6j9ey0/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2025%20Jan%202015%2018.52.25.png?dl=0)

On iOS 8, this code executes flawlessly, I don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Could it be because your right constraints are set to the margins? I think 7.1 didn't do constraints to margins.

Comment: Tried it, no change :(

Comment: found what the problem was. Check my answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Just remove:

```
[cell.contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

form:

```
- (void)configureCell:(TableViewCell *)cell withDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {...}
```

Comment: Yes, that does fix the layout issue, but it produces a new one, because it's making Autoresizing layout constraints. What I'm losing like this is wrapping long titles and getting bigger cell heights. But since I can't figure out how to make it work, your answer is what I should be doing. Thanks :)